# Register to subscription manager failed in RHEL

Tags: redhat

I'm trying register subscription manager but it gives me following error.

[root@localhost rhsm]# sudo subscription-manager register

Registering to: subscription.rhsm.redhat.com:443/subscription
Username: redhat
Password: 
Unable to verify server's identity: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)

I tried every possible solution from redhat forums but didn't help any.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a corporate network with a proxy which decrypts and reencrypts TLS connections?  In this case, you should exempt the Red Hat CDN domains from that.  See [cdn.redhat.com X.509 certificate](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1373143) for some background.

Another cause of such problems could be Wifi portal login pages, especially if this happens within a VM and you use bridge networking instead of NAT (so that the external network sees another MAC).

Comment: I'm not on corporate network. I'm using my company laptop but i haven't connected to vpn.

Comment: Then your ISP is doing something to the HTTPS connection or there is some sort of Wifi portal page which is interfering.

Comment: Not sure if ISP is doing something. I checked my router and see HTTP/HTTPS isn't blocked.

Answer (score 0):

one option would be (as sudo) vim /etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf then set ssl = false.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with a system that I didn't run `subscription-manager` for a long time on. Also actually it was a cloned install on another computer to begin with, so idk if client certificates are bound to machine information.

Anyway, I was getting

```
Unknown server reply (HTTP error code 400: Bad Request):
<html><13>
<head><title>400 The SSL certificate error</title></head><13>
<body><13>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center><13>
<center>The SSL certificate error</center><13>
<hr><center>openresty</center><13>
</body><13>
</html><13>
```

Which to my unedrstanding is a problem with client certificate.

So I had to do:

```
sudo subscription-manager clean
sudo subscription-manager register
```

Then maybe clean-up any unused systems from https://access.redhat.com